# How to build Android gradle project that contains modules with different compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and minSdkVersion?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Android library project is made up of four modules:

- project

  - base
  - factory
  - v14
  - v18

Here's a screenshot of this setup from IntelliJ:

[image: modules]

My modules utilize very specific Android SDK level settings:

- base

  - `compileSdkVersion 19`
  - `minSdkVersion 14`
  - `targetSdkVersion 19`
- factory

  - `compileSdkVersion 19`
  - `minSdkVersion 14`
  - `targetSdkVersion 19`
- v14

  - `compileSdkVersion 17`
  - `minSdkVersion 14`
  - `targetSdkVersion 17`
- v18

  - `compileSdkVersion 18`
  - `minSdkVersion 18`
  - `targetSdkVersion 18`

As newer versions of Android are released, the base and factory modules can have their `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` levels follow along. However, v14 and v18 both absolutely can't follow suit with this.

My modules depend on each other in very specific ways:

- base

  - does not depend on any other module
- factory

  - depends on base, v14, and v18
- v14

  - depends on base
- v18

  - depends on base

So when I go to build my project, I receive this error:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':v14:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.
```

When building via terminal using `./gradlew build --stacktrace`, I get a little bit more information:

```
:v14:processReleaseManifest
[/blahblah/project/v14/build/exploded-aar/blahblah/base/unspecified/AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion='17'> but library uses targetSdkVersion='19'
:v14:processReleaseManifest FAILED
```

And here's my v14 `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example.v14">

    <application />

</manifest>
```

(My base `AndroidManifest.xml` file is nearly exactly identical)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example">

    <application />

</manifest>
```

This error doesn't make very much sense to me. First of all, I don't specify version levels in any of my four different `AndroidManifest.xml` files (and I instead let those values be inherited through my four different `build.gradle` files).

Secondly, I don't have a "Main manifest". The base module is probably the closest thing I have to that, and so how exactly the v14 module ended up as the "Main manifest" I find pretty confusing.

Finally, if this project setup isn't possible, then I'm shocked. This module configuration is absolutely trivial to set up in an Eclipse-style project. It's how I've been building the library for months now.

By the way, my end goal is for this to all compile down to a single `.jar` file, which my current Eclipse-style project can do. It's just that I'm trying to completely migrate over to gradle and not be left behind on a sinking ship...

Any ideas? If necessary, I can post my various gradle files (`build.gradle`, `settings.gradle`...). Just trying to avoid completely overloading this post.

### Edit (May 27th, 2014)

Added a screenshot of my module configuration to the beginning of this post.

Comment: "This module configuration is absolutely trivial to set up in an Eclipse-style project" -- only because your requested settings are ignored. For Ant/Eclipse, the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` API levels that matter at runtime are the ones on the app, not the library. What do you think that you are getting out of those settings?

Comment: Android's internal android.media.IRemoteControlDisplay.Stub class is different in API 18 versus APIs 14 - 17. Therefore I must have different child classes for it as well (one that encompasses 14 - 17 and another just for 18). Such is the hole I've found myself in.

Comment: At best, that would impact your build target (a.k.a., `compileSdkVersion`). And unless you work for a device manufacturer (whereby you can know precisely what those internal classes are like for your devices), please don't mess with those. With respect to your problem, I believe they are enforcing `compileSdkVersion` compatibility because AARs are compiled, as opposed to source-based library projects. From the `exploded-aar` of the error, it feels like your modules are library projects, which might cause you problems anyway getting a single JAR at the end.

Comment: Yes I understand your concern! But my implementation actually works pretty dang great across all of the devices I've tested on (about 10 or so of different manufacturers and types). But okay, based on this conversation it's looking like I may not be able to move this library forward to gradle. I'll keep investigating though, thanks for your time.

Comment: By module do you mean flavour?

Comment: @maclir I just added a screenshot to my question, does this help?

Comment: If you have at the end single jar with all classes that can be accessed by an application that depends on your lib. Then why do you bother with separate modules? Is it just for easier maintenance? Or maybe your goal is to make app to pick up correct class based on minSdk property?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flavours according to [Gradle plugin user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-Flavor-Configuration):

> `defaultConfig` provides the base configuration for all flavors and
>   each flavor can override any value.

For example you can have the following setup in your build.gradle file:

```
    android {

    ...

        defaultConfig {
            ...
            compileSdkVersion 19
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        productFlavors {
            base {
                compileSdkVersion 19
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 19
            }

            factory {
                compileSdkVersion 19
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 19
            }

            v14 {
                compileSdkVersion 17
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 17
            }

            v18 {
                compileSdkVersion 18
                minSdkVersion 18
                targetSdkVersion 18
            }
        }
    }
```

Moreover you don't need to set the package name in the manifest either. You can set them like the following:

```
android {
    ...

    productFlavors {
        base {
            packageName "com.example"
            ...
        }

        v14 {
            packageName "com.example.v14"
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ScootrNova mentioned that he produce at the end single jar. But using flavours produce multiple outputs.